# Video Freezes System in Ubuntu 20.04 or 22.04

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, google-chrome, video, 22.04

I'm currently using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS on a Dell Precision Laptop with the latest bios firmware and Nvidia Quatro T2000 graphics. The laptop has a Intel i9 processor and 32GB RAM and a 1TB NVMe SDD.

At least once or twice per day the user interface will freeze if I'm watching a video, or if I'm in a video chat, whilst in Google Chrome, Brave, or Firefox browsers. It also happens during Zoom calls (with the Zoom app). During the freeze, everything on the screen stops and I can't move the mouse pointer.

If I have other applications open in the background, I can press "Alt + Tab" a few times and it sometimes allows me to switch to another application. I can then switch back to the browser with the video (which briefly shows a load of colored static lines across the video), and then it starts working again. However, if I don't have another application running in the background, "Alt + Tab" doesn't work and there's no way to recover other than to hard reboot the system. Other people in the video meeting can still see me moving and hear me talking, and I can hear them, but my screen is frozen.

So far I have:

- Disabled the "Use Hardware Acceleration" option in browsers
- Disabled the "GPU Raterization" flag in browsers
- Switched between two versions of Nvidia proprietary driver (460 & 515)
- Switched to Intel graphics, disabling the Nvidia graphics
- Upgraded to numerous different kernel versions over time (currently on 5.15.0-43-generic)
- Captured the journalctl logs during multiple freezes, which show nothing in the logs at the time of the freeze(s)
- I've also tried a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and I get the same issue

None of it has made any difference. Has anyone else had this issue at all?

Here's some system output:

```
free -h
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31849        2952       26003         537        2893       27940
Swap:           7811           0        7811


sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60

ls -l ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 0
```

Edit: This happens in all browsers and in the Zoom app, not just Chrome.

Comment: Using Zoom 5.17 on Ubuntu 22.04, I found that it was using masses of CPU time, and this amount went up until the system jammed up and had to be powered off. I then changed to Xorg graphics system by logging-off and on and this performed a little better, ie it coped with a video conference. So you could try system monitor and see if this is also a problem with your system...

Answer (score 0):

Try using Xorg graphics system (log-out, select "Ubuntu on Xorg" option from an icon at botton-left of screen, then log-in again). Some apps seem to work better using different graphics systems (see comment above)